# wget - download external images

Tags: images, download

I'm using `wget -A` to download images from a page.
This works fine, when images are hosted on the same domain as the page.
But this won't download images hotlinked from other pages (e.g. imageshack)

How can I download the external images as well using wget or similar tool?

Answer (score 6):

You need the `-H` (resp. `--span-hosts`) parameter. It enables downloading of linked resources that are hosted at different hosts/domains.

In addition you may block specific domains with `--exclude-domains` (Example: `--exclude-domains=example.com,example.org`)

Comment: The first sentence solves the problem as per the post, in my opinion. Someone should mark this answer as correct.

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the domain you allow wget to follow using -D [domain list] or --domains=[domain list] (coma separated)

Note: I don't know if it handles wildcards.

Answer (score 0):

Some adminsys (me included) [block the wget user-agent](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-lighttpd-block-useragent.html) on some files to avoid hotlinking (for example).

There are also other tools like wget: [cURL](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html), [httpie](https://github.com/jkbr/httpie/), etc.. but they also can be blocked by their user-agent.

So it might not be a problem from you, but from domain you are querying.